# Java Spring @Value annotation, and parameters

Tags: java, spring

So, I have an environment property that is supposed to reflect what environment my app is running in.

```
@Value("${environment}")
private String environmentName; //This will be set as sandbox, staging, production
```

I also have a feature flag (feature is called 'superFeature.enable') that should be set based on what environment the app has been deployed in.

```
//Config file
superFeature.enable.sandbox=true
superFeature.enable.staging=false
superFeature.enable.production=false


//@Service annotated class containing call to configuration

@Value("${superFeature.enable.{environment}:false}")
private boolean isSuperFeatureEnabled;
```

At the moment, when I run my app in my sandbox environment, `isSuperFeatureEnabled` is always false. Is my syntax correct for the above code snippet? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have put

```
@Value("${superFeature.enable.{environmentName}:false}")
```

there?
This is just a guess, I'm afraid. It looked like an inconsistency there. But then, I don't know in which context and order these two statements above are executed, so I don't know where which variables are known.
I would suggest getting some more information first. Like, what happens if you replace the {environment} with the expected string for your environment, can you get the environment value in your code at that point. I don't know if it is even possible to have this kind of double indirection at all.

Comment: So, your suggestion is that I should pass in the name of the Java variable (environmentName)  rather than the name of the configuration (environment)?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the following(environment also enclosed within placeholder syntax starting with $) :

```
@Value("${superFeature.enable.${environment}:false}")
```